# If A is a positive definite matrix, how to show that the product of any two diagonal elements, $A_{ii} A_{jj}$, is greater than $|A_{ij}|^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

This seems like a basic linear algebra proof but I am stumped.

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ be a positive definite matrix, defined as $u^TAu > 0$ for all $u \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus\{0\}$.

How does one show:

$A_{ii} A_{jj} > |A_{ij}|^2$ when $i \ne j$

?

I have tried using different values of $u$ in the definition of positive definite but have not achieved that inequality. Eg I tried $u = [0, ...,  A_{jj}, ..., 1, ..., 0]^T $, where the $A_{jj}$ and $1$ are at the $i$th and $j$th positions, respectively, which yields

$u^TAu = A_{ii}A_{jj} + |A_{ij}|^2 + A_{ji}A_{ii} + A_{jj}A_{ij} > 0$

which has the terms I'm looking for, but does not appear useful for proving the inequality .

Comment: Hint: One can show that all of $A$'s principal submatrices are positive definite. In particular, a $2$-by-$2$ principal submatrix is positive definite, in which case its determinant is positive (the expression that you have).

Comment: Try to use Sylvester's criterion.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$ be an index set, and let $A[\alpha]$ be the submatrix of $A$ whose rows and columns are labelled by $\alpha$. Then $A[\alpha]$ is positive definite. Indeed, let $x\in \mathbb R^n$ with $x[\alpha]\neq 0$ and $x[\alpha^C]=0$. Thus,
$x[\alpha]^TA[\alpha]x[\alpha]=x^TAx>0$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $A[\alpha]$ is positive definite.

In particular, if $\alpha=\{i,j\}$, where $i\neq j$ (say $i<j$), then $A[\alpha]=\begin{bmatrix} A_{ii}& A_{ij}\\ A_{ij}& A_{jj}\end{bmatrix}$ is positive definite, and so it has positive determinant, that is,
$A_{ii}A_{jj}-|A_{ij}|^2=\det(A)>0$. (This proof still works for complex positive definite matrices, and one also gets a corresponding inequality for positive semidefinite matrices.)

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: Wait - does this assume $A_{ij}$ equals $A_{ji}$? Is that necessarily true?

Comment: By definition of positive (semi) definiteness, it is necessarily symmetric. In the complex case, it is necessarily Hermitian.

Comment: Also, in the complex case, you really need that absolute value and that $A_{ji}=\overline{A_{ij}}$. But in the real case, I kept the absolute value and dropped the conjugate to be in line with your notation.

Comment: thank you so much for the additional clarification

Comment: glad to help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=xe^i+ye^j$ so $u^TAu=x^2[A_{ii}+2zA_{ij}+z^2A_{jj}]>0,\,z:=y/x$ for all $x,\,y\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. Therefore, the discriminant $(2A_{ij})-2A_{ii}A_{jj}<0$.